# Scan functionality not working

Tags: windows-7, services, scanner

I have a Brother MFC-7860DW.  It is set up wireless.  I can print just fine but the scanner will not work.  I keep getting the error message that says:

MFC7860-DW LAN cannot be found
 .
 .
 .
(CC4-202-00000008)

I can also scan when I have a wired connection to the printer.  It just doesn't work wireless.  I have spent hours on the phone with Brother tech support and they say everything on the Brother side is working correctly.  There is something on my machine that is blocking wireless communication to the printer.

When I turn off all anti-virus and windows firewall the problem persists.  The only way I can get it to work wireless is when I boot my computer in diagnostic mode (through msconfig.exe) with only basic devices and services.  So one of the services I have running is blocking the printer communication but going through them one by one would take weeks.

I exported a list of the services from Services.msc but I cannot figure out a way to attach a file and it's too long to paste into the body of this post.

Thanks for the help.
Kyle

Comment: Does it work with another computer(s)?

Comment: Yes, it works with another computer and it used to work with this computer.  There was some update or something that broke this one and I can't figure out what it is.  I think I did an adobe update and accidentally installed McAffee.  I uninstalled it but maybe it left something that is causing the problem.  I don't know.  I really don't want to do a format/reload.

Comment: Those are important details to include in the question. Now that you have given more details, use System Restore to go back to a date before you did the update. There is a possibility it may undo what caused the problem. Also, check the event viewer to see if there is a more detailed error message. Other than that, about the only other thing you could try is running `sfc /scannow` from an elevated command prompt to see if it finds/fixes corrupt system files.